# How do you create a Main.storyboard in Xamarin 6.1.2?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

If I create a Xamarin iOS project I get a Main.storyboard in the solution.
If I create a Xamarin Mac project there is no Main.storyboard.
All the documents I'm reading on how to link an action to a button require a storyboard.

How do you create a Main.storyboard file in Xamarin for a Mac solution/project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens if you target 10.9 as the minimum Mac OSX version to support when creating a solution.

Selecting 10.10 or 10.11 when creating a Mac solution creates a solution with storyboard support.

Comment: In the "older" macOS versions you use an user interface ".xib",  Storyboard support was added to OS X 10.10. If you need to target 10.7-10.11 then using xibs is the way to go.

Comment: You can see this in Apple's docs here - https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434499-storyboard?language=objc